# r: looping through a list of lists and appending the results to a data frame

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have the following lists, `list1` and `list2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1a <- data.frame(
  index = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  first_column = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  second_column = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
)

df1b <- data.frame(
  index = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  first_column = c(4, 2, 3, 1),
  second_column = c(8, 6, 7, 5)
)

list1 <- dplyr::lst(df1a, df1b)

df2a <- data.frame(
  index = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  first_column = c(4, 3, 2, 1),
  second_column = c(8, 7, 6, 5)
)

df2b <- data.frame(
  index = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  first_column = c(8, 2, 6, 5),
  second_column = c(4, 3, 7, 1)
)

list2 <- dplyr::lst(df2a, df2b)
```

This is the function that I want to run on `list1` and `list2`:

```r
output_mean <- function(subset, name) {
  subset %>%
    group_by(index) %>%
    summarize(across(c(first_column, second_column), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    mutate(type = name) %>%
    print()
}
```

Now, I can loop through *one* list:

```r
x <- list()
for (i in names(list1)) {
   ps <- output_mean(list1[[i]], i)
   x[[paste0(i)]] <- ps
  }

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   index first_column second_column type 
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1          1.5           5.5 df1a 
#> 2     2          3.5           7.5 df1a 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   index first_column second_column type 
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1            3             7 df1b 
#> 2     2            2             6 df1b
```

And then I can put the results into one dataframe:

```r
all1 <- do.call(rbind, x)
all1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   index first_column second_column type 
#> * <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1          1.5           5.5 df1a 
#> 2     2          3.5           7.5 df1a 
#> 3     1          3             7   df1b 
#> 4     2          2             6   df1b
```

But what if I want to put `list1` and `list2` into a `big_list` and loop through it?
This is what I have tried:

```r
big_list <- list(list1, list2)

y <- list()
for (j in big_list){
  x <- list()
    for (i in names(j)) {
       ps <- output_mean(j[[i]], i)
       x[[paste0(i)]] <- ps
      }

  all = do.call(rbind, x)
}
```

The loop works, but then only two data frames are appended in `all`, as it is understandable, as the outer loop overwrites `all`.

```r
all
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   index first_column second_column type 
#> * <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1          3.5           7.5 df2a 
#> 2     2          1.5           5.5 df2a 
#> 3     1          5             3.5 df2b 
#> 4     2          5.5           4   df2b
```

I have tried many different things, but I can't manage to get the four data frames appended together in a single 4 by 8 dataframe.

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could initialize 'y' with `length` same as the `length` of `big_list`, loop over the sequence of 'big_list', (it may be also better to initialize 'x' with the `length` of the inner list.

```
y <- vector('list', length(big_list))
for (j in seq_along(big_list)){
  x <- list()
    for (i in seq_along(big_list[[j]])) {
       ps <- output_mean(big_list[[j]][[i]], names(big_list[[j]])[i])
       x[[i]] <- ps
      }

  y[[j]]  <- do.call(rbind, x)
}

 out <- do.call(rbind, y)
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  index first_column second_column type 
#  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#1     1          1.5           5.5 df1a 
#2     2          3.5           7.5 df1a 
#3     1          3             7   df1b 
#4     2          2             6   df1b 
#5     1          3.5           7.5 df2a 
#6     2          1.5           5.5 df2a 
#7     1          5             3.5 df2b 
#8     2          5.5           4   df2b
```

---

This can be done more easily with `map`

```
library(purrr)
out1 <- map_dfr(big_list, ~ imap_dfr(.x, ~ output_mean(.x, .y)))
```

-output

```
out1
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  index first_column second_column type 
#  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#1     1          1.5           5.5 df1a 
#2     2          3.5           7.5 df1a 
#3     1          3             7   df1b 
#4     2          2             6   df1b 
#5     1          3.5           7.5 df2a 
#6     2          1.5           5.5 df2a 
#7     1          5             3.5 df2b 
#8     2          5.5           4   df2b
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you see, `type` should be the data frames' names (`df1a`, `df1b` etc.) and all the data frames should be appended together in a 4 by 8 data frame. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Emy Did you meant the output as the updated

Comment: almost, I would like them combined together in one dataframe. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Emy i add a more compact version with `map/imap`

Comment: looks great thanks! Any recommendation for learning more about `lists` and `map/imap`?

Comment: @Emy you may check the vignette for tidyverse

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to store `big_list` as a concatenated list instead of nested list.

```
big_list <- c(list1, list2)
```

If you do this your original code would work as it is -

```
y <- list()
for (i in names(big_list)) {
    ps <- output_mean(big_list[[i]], i)
    y[[paste0(i)]] <- ps
}

all = do.call(rbind, y)
all

#  index first_column second_column type 
#*  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#1     1          1.5           5.5 df1a 
#2     2          3.5           7.5 df1a 
#3     1          3             7   df1b 
#4     2          2             6   df1b 
#5     1          3.5           7.5 df2a 
#6     2          1.5           5.5 df2a 
#7     1          5             3.5 df2b 
#8     2          5.5           4   df2b
```

---

It is also easier to apply the function using `purrr` :

```
purrr::imap_dfr(big_list, output_mean)
```

and base R :

```
do.call(rbind, Map(output_mean, big_list, names(big_list)))
```